# Why inefficient factorial computation is...efficient (and fast)?

Tags: c++, recursion, memoization

I wrote this simple program to test the [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) technique:

```
int main() {
    function<double(double)> f = [&f](double i) -> double {
        if (i == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return i * f(i - 1);
    };
    cout << f(100) << endl;
}
```

I was expecting to execute this code in several seconds (since its inefficient recursion), but actually it took few ms...Why? I think that there is a some compiler optimization under the hood, but I don't get what happens.

**BONUS QUESTION:**
Can you please give me a simple program which its execution is inefficient (compiler optimizations or not), so I can test the memoization benefits?

Comment: Several seconds to compute 100 multiplications? Are you running this on an abacus?

Comment: It might be a case of tail-recursion optimization, or it might be something else (like not that many calls, really). The only way to know for sure is to look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: Your input number is too small to show the disadvantage of a recursive implementation. It still computes only 100 multiplications - the increasing stack size is not yet a problem. Try with 10000 or larger to note the problem. Answer to bonus question: Try fibonacci sequence: `f(i) := f(i-1) + f(i-2)` with two base cases `f(0) := 1; f(1) := 1` Since it calls `f` recursively more than once, your stack grows faster than linear with `i`.

Comment: Just a hint - try to calculate Fibonacci using recursive approach (or just multiple the result by `f(i - 2)`)

Comment: Why do you believe recursion is inefficient?

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov +1 because you made me laugh, but with f(1000) I can assure you that it doesn't work so fast as 1000 computations :) Computing this functions is not simply "make 1000 multiplications", but recursively calling 1000 times a function (which implies Activation Record allocation on the stack and a lot of other stuff).

Comment: @justHelloworld: Why don't you try running f(1000) and see? It might not be *as fast* as using a loop but you will definitely not be able to notice the difference.

Comment: @justHelloWorld Almost nothing happens for these function calls. The stack space is already allocated and only reserved indirectly by increasing the stack pointer. You could inspect the assembly...

Comment: You should try with an actual recursive function, not with an object that looks like a recursive function.

Comment: Ok using fibonacci I can manage smaller numbers which are computed in several seconds (already from fib(30) ). So the bonus question is solved. But nobody told me why with f(100) it takes few ms and f(1000) it's a neverending story.

Comment: To clarify: the `f(i - 1)` in the lambda isn't a direct recursive call (not too surprising if you consider that the `function` is not the same object as the lambda). It call's `f`'s `operator()(double)`, which in turn calls `operator()(double)` of the lambda object that `f` wraps (and so on). There is a lot of indirection hidden behind all that syntactic sugar, and the compiler might not be able to unwrap all of it.

Comment: Side-question: with f(100), wouldn't you also run out of space in the double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memoization technique is meant to be applied to optimize expensive function calls. The factorial function is not the case. C++ is extremely fast so a factorial function call will never take more than a few millisecons to compute. (at least if not using multi precision). factorial(100) is "only" 100 multiplications so nothing for C++.

If this is just for testing or demonstration purpose, I would simply introduce a delay in the function call (sleep, long dummy loop or whatever). 
With the memorization implemented, that delay shouldn't happened so it runs in "almost" no time.

This is an example of what I would do. **factorial** is the expensive function. **memo_factorial** is the wrap of it with the memoization technic implemented.
In the first call to the function, the dictionary of input and outputs is updated, in the following calls with the same input, the value previously stored is return so the "real" function is not executed again.

```
#define ELAPSE(cmd) { clock_t s = clock();\
    long ret = cmd;\
    cout << "\t" << #cmd\
         << " = " << ret \
         << "\t(" << (clock()-s)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " secs)" \
         << endl; }

long factorial(long i) {
    for(clock_t s = clock(); (clock()-s)<CLOCKS_PER_SEC; );
    return i<=1 ? 1 : i*factorial(i-1);
}
long memo_factorial(long i) {
    static map<long,long> saved;
    map<long,long>::const_iterator it = saved.find(i);
    return ( it==saved.end() ) ? (saved[i] = memo_factorial(i)) : it->second;
}

int main() {
    cout << "first execution WITHOUT memoization" << endl;
    for(int i=1; i<5; ++i) {
        ELAPSE( memo_factorial(i) )
    }

    cout << "second execution WITH memoization" << endl;
    for(int i=1; i<5; ++i) {
        ELAPSE( memo_factorial(i) )
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

```
first execution WITHOUT memoization
    memo_factorial(i) = 1   (1 secs)
    memo_factorial(i) = 2   (1 secs)
    memo_factorial(i) = 6   (1 secs)
    memo_factorial(i) = 24  (1 secs)
second execution WITH memoization
    memo_factorial(i) = 1   (0 secs)
    memo_factorial(i) = 2   (0 secs)
    memo_factorial(i) = 6   (0 secs)
    memo_factorial(i) = 24  (0 secs)
```

Hope you find it useful.

Regards,
Alex

NOTE: factorial is normally define on integer values. Of course, it is just a sequence of multiplications hence it can be applied on other types.

Comment: `memo_factorial()` should call itself recursively, rather than call `factorial()`. That way, a call to `memo_factorial(100)` would memoize all values where `i <= 100`, rather than just a single value. This is a critical part of memoizing recursive functions.

Comment: Thanks @JørgenFogh. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Memoization is primarily a technique for improving the [algorithmic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) of a computation, not avoiding recursion. That is why the Fibonacci numbers are a much better example to use than the factorial function (even though the WikiPedia page uses the factorial function).

Take a look at the figures in the [wikibook on dynamic programming](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithms/Dynamic_Programming). All the calls which are crossed out in the second figure are the savings you get from memoization. With the factorial function, nothing would be crossed out.